# Component Pagination for Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, pagination, joomla-extensions, joomla2.5, joomla-component

I am writing a new component for Joomla 2.5 and I am having problems wrapping my head around paginiation on the frontend(user site).

I have looked at the core component (com_content) to see how they do it and I am still unable to replicate the same. So when I put the line in my view.html.php file:

```
$pagination = $this->get('Pagination');
```

I get the JPagination Object and can print it out but I can not get them to display properly like below (how they do it in com_content)

```
echo $this->pagination->getPagesCounter();
echo $this->pagination->getPagesLinks();
```

What am I missing? What else do I need to have? Do I need to have more functions in my Models/thisview.php file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you should be doing like so:

```
$pagination = $this->get('Pagination');
echo $pagination->getPagesCounter();
```

Comment: You are right, I was looking all over the place and finally figured it out last night, I wanted to kick something, haha Thanks! I was going to delete this cause it was just me over looking it, but since you answered, I'll leave it up. Cheers!